# Can we change the table or column name of aspnet membership?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-membership

Can we change the table or column name of aspnet membership.

If yes? then what will be the effects ?

Comment: But more importantly, why would you want to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The stored procedures and any relationships dependent on the fields would break.  You can do it, you would write your own custom Membership Provider.